# Creating multiple Tkinter pages with a for loop

Tags: python, list, class, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter GUI with a lot of pages. A lot of them have the same display of different databases.

I want to create multiple pages following the list of databases

I have a list of pandas dataframes in a list called Databases and I want to create pages automatically fitted to the databases

```py
global Pages
Pages=[]

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        Pages_List=[Studies_List]+Pages
        self.frames = {}
        for F in Pages_List: #dont forget to add the different pages
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Studies_Page)

    def show_frame(self, c):

        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class Studies_Page(tk.Frame): #Should, from each Site, show only  the XRays corresponding to this Site. Plots sheet is an option too.
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,background=bg_color)
        self.controller=controller
        tk.Label(self, text="Home > Studies ",bg=bg_color,font=('Arial',9,'italic')).pack(side='top')
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose the Study you want the data from :",bg=bg_color, font=TITLE_FONT) 
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        Studies_frame=tk.Frame(self,bg=bg_color)

        ############ Studies Buttons 
        for i in range(len(Databases)):
                tk.Button(Studies_frame, text=Pages[i]['Study'][0],command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Pages[i])).pack(in_=Studies_frame)
                tk.Label(Studies_frame, text=" ",bg=bg_color,font=('Arial',11,)).pack()

        Studies_frame.pack(expand=True,side='top')


for i in range(len(Databases)):
   class page(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            self.controller=controller

            df=Databases[i]
            f=tk.Frame(self)
            f.pack()
            self.table=pt=Table(f,dataframe=df)
            pt.show()

            return

    Pages.append(page)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.title("X-Rays App")
    app.mainloop()
```

It is particularly needed because I have multiple buttons in the startpage, each of them leading to a database.
I was expecting a page for each database but instead every occurence of the Pages List returned the last list.

I have a lot of pages to create with tkinter and they have a lot in common so I would like to use lists with classes in a dynamic way but I didn't find how. 
I tried changing the class name everytime but it still returns the last database of the Databases lists

Comment: I'm not sure but I think problem can be `i` - class may not get value from `i` but use reference to this variable and get value from `i` later - after `for` loop` - when you create instance of this class and `i` has already last value from list `range(len(...))`\. I would rather create one class and later create different instances of this class but with different values in arguments in `__init__`(..., arguments)` and every instance should keep different value from `i`

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot !

Answer (score 2):

There are no reasons to redefine the `class Page(tk.Frame):` multiple times in a for loop.

What you should probably do, is create instances of that class inside the loop.

Maybe like this:

```
class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, db_index):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self.db_index = db_index

        df = Databases[self.db_index]
        self.pack()
        self.table = Table(f, dataframe=df)
        pt.show()

pages = []
for idx in range(len(database_collection)):
    pages.append(Page(parent, controller, idx))   # create an instance of Page
```

Comment: I would add `i` as argument - `Page(parent, controller, i )`

Comment: why does the ’’’self..pack()’’’ do ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
When I try this, it says that the name 'parent' is not defined ? seems like I have to put everything into a class or something ?

Comment: `class Page(tk.Frame)` is a subclass of `tk.Frame` - `self.pack()` (with only one dot, that was a typo), positions it inside its parent, as you would do with a `tk.Frame`.  You will need to create a `root = tk.Tk()`, and pass it as a parent to `Page`, but because you did not provided one in the code you posted (you did not provide a `Database` either), I did not see why I should.

Comment: My bad, it's because my code is very long and I didn't know what would be usefull to put.  The databases is from my company, I cannot share it... 
Thank you for your help! 
I'll have a last question : the controller is not defined either... do you know how I can do please? I'm really new at this